# View with SentryOne Plan Explorer from SSMS context menu doesn't work if Plan Explorer is already open

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, execution-plan

I am using SentryOne Plan Exporer.

When I right click in the execution plan pane in SSMS, the first option is

> View with SentryOne Plan Explorer

Clicking this fires up an instance of Plan Explorer and opens the execution plan.

If I leave Plan Explorer open and then run another query in SSMS and right click in the Execution Plan pane and once again click View With SentryOne Plan Explorer, nothing happens. I would have thought either a new tab or new instance of Plan Explorer would open or a new tab in the already running instance?

Am I doing something wrong or is this a feature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, the best option is to just generate the plan from within [SentryOne Plan Explorer](https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer) in the first place, instead of switching back and forth. You get much richer metrics this way, because it captures a bunch of things SSMS doesn't, including actual costs, I/O, and Index Analysis.

But yes, this was a defect in an earlier release, that came about after the add-in had to change yet again due to the evolution of SSMS and how it works with add-ins.

Comment: changing the connection is a bit messy, specially if you have 100s of servers each with over 50 dbs. one thing that can be done though is to generate the xml query plan and paste this one into sQL Sentry.  I would like if the servernames and databases used would be kind of "saved" to be used again, same as ssms does with servernames